# javascript mqtt websocket works fine in localhost, not working in https server

Tags: javascript, websocket, https, mqtt, paho

javascript mqtt websocket connection works fine in localhost, not
working in https server

Code

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Hello MQTT World</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="paho-mqtt.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    var client = new Paho.Client('myserver.com',8083,'asdfg');
    client.connect({
        reconnect:true,
        onSuccess:function(){
            console.log('Connected');
            client.subscribe("/abcd/+/#");  // Where 16 is the bspid
        }
    });
    client.onMessageArrived=function(message){
        console.log(message);
    };
    </script>
    
    <ul id="logger"></ul>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Fehlermeldung

```
> Error paho-mqtt.js:1054 Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://myserver.com/pis/monitoring/mqtt.html' was loaded over HTTPS,
> but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint
> 'ws://myserver.com:8083/mqtt'. This request has been blocked; this
> endpoint must be available over WSS.
> LibraryFactory.ClientImpl._doConnect @ paho-mqtt.js:1054
> LibraryFactory.ClientImpl.connect @ paho-mqtt.js:887 Client.connect @
> paho-mqtt.js:2028 (anonymous) @ mqtt.html:12 paho-mqtt.js:1054
> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure
> WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over
> HTTPS.
>     at ClientImpl.LibraryFactory.ClientImpl._doConnect (https://myserver.com/pis/monitoring/paho-mqtt.js:1054:19)
>     at ClientImpl.LibraryFactory.ClientImpl.connect (https://myserver.com/pis/monitoring/paho-mqtt.js:887:10)
>     at Client.connect (https://myserver.com/pis/monitoring/paho-mqtt.js:2028:12)
>     at https://myserver.com/pis/monitoring/mqtt.html:12:8 LibraryFactory.ClientImpl._doConnect @ paho-mqtt.js:1054
> LibraryFactory.ClientImpl.connect @ paho-mqtt.js:887 Client.connect @
> paho-mqtt.js:2028 (anonymous) @ mqtt.html:12
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear about what the problem is

```
> Error paho-mqtt.js:1054 Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://myserver.com/pis/monitoring/mqtt.html' was loaded over HTTPS,
> but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint
> 'ws://myserver.com:8083/mqtt'. This request has been blocked; this
> endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

The browser is enforcing a secure origin policy. This means that any resource accessed from a page loaded via HTTPS must be accessed by an equally secure fashion. So in this case if you load the page via HTTP you must use a secure Web Socket connection to connect to the MQTT broker.

You will need to enable Secure Websockets on your broker and either use a `wss://` URL or add `useSSL: true` to the options passed to the `client.connect()` function.

The second option is to have what ever is serving up you webpage proxy for the broker and do the SSL/TLS termination there. e.g. Nginx or Apache.

Comment: Thank you very much for your exact answer. I am trying wss:// https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html

Comment: Now I am facing trouble in wss://.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372295/configure-ssl-tls-support-for-mosquitto2

Comment: But that is a separate issue to the question asked and answered here.